# unicorn folder for pid is not writable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, unicorn

I'm using capistrano and now want to start using unicorn on my server, so I have this in my deploy.rb:

```
set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('/home/webadmin/www/my_app/shared/pids', '/home/webadmin/www/my_app/current/config', '/home/webadmin/www/my_app/shared/sockets')

set :unicorn_conf, "/home/webadmin/www/my_app/current/config/unicorn.rb"
set :unicorn_pid, "/home/webadmin/www/my_app/shared/pids/unicorn.pid"
```

now when I'm deploying to server I have this error:

```
 /home/webadmin/www/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:91:in `block in reload'

 directory for pid=/www/my_app/shared/pids/unicorn.pid not writable
 (
 ArgumentError
 )
```

I have this folder on server and granted permissions to it via `chmod go-w` but still have this error

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, double-check the `chmod` command you mentioned. `chmod go-w`, if I understand it right, should:

- *remove* write privileges
- for Group and Other users (not Owner)

SSH onto the server, locate that folder and do `ls -la` to verify that the permissions are right. For example, all-write permissions for the User (owner) and Group might look like:

```
drwxrwxr-x ...
```

whereas read-only permissions might look like:

```
dr-xr-xr-x
```

Comment: And you've verified that the folder is owned by the correct user (eg. not root)? If so, then check the parent directory too - sometimes if a service is denied access to read a parent folder, it can't even see the child folder. That's all I can say though, I'm not a sysadmin and am out of ideas. :-( Good luck@